# How can I travel recursively in a picture / matrix

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a function which separates a pictures into areas by taking each pixel and search recursively

if any of it's 8 nighbors are similar (by comparing their hue value) and then painting over them with the same color.

I started simple in (0,0) and tried to "travel" recursivley to any similar pixel and painting them all in red until i get stuck.

It worked fine on a 55x55 picture but when i tried 300x55 i got the famous `StackOverflow` exception.

Travel function (after some edits, addad boolean matrix to flag visited pixels):

```
     private static void area( int x, int y){
        //img and visited[][] are global variables
        int height = img.getHeight();
        int width = img.getWidth();
        visited[x][y] = true;
        int color = img.getRGB(x,y); // store before painting


      //  if(img.getRGB(x,y) != Color.RED.getRGB())
            img.setRGB(x, y, Color.RED.getRGB());
     //   else
     //       return;


        //spread to 8 directions clockwise
        //top
        if ((y - 1) >= 0)
            if(!visited[x][y-1] && hsbSimilarity(color,img.getRGB(x,y - 1)))
                area( x, y - 1);
        //top right
        if ((x + 1) < width && (y - 1) >= 0)
            if(!visited[x+1][y-1] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x + 1,y - 1)))
                area( x + 1, y - 1);
        //right
        if((x + 1) < width)
            if(!visited[x+1][y] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x + 1,y)))
                area( x + 1, y);
        //bot right
        if((x + 1) < width && (y + 1) < height)
            if(!visited[x+1][y+1] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x + 1,y + 1)))
                area(x + 1, y + 1);
        //bot
        if((y + 1) < height)
            if(!visited[x][y+1] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x,y + 1)))
                area(x, y + 1);
        //bot left
        if((x - 1) >= 0 && (y + 1) < height)
            if(!visited[x-1][y+1] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x - 1,y + 1)))
                area(x - 1, y + 1);
        //left
        if((x - 1) >= 0)
            if(!visited[x-1][y] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x - 1,y)))
                area( x - 1, y);
        //top left
        if((x - 1) >= 0 && (y - 1) >= 0)
            if(!visited[x-1][y-1] && hsbSimilarity(color, img.getRGB(x - 1,y - 1)))
                area(x - 1, y - 1);
    }
```

Comparison function:

```
    private static boolean hsbSimilarity( int rgb1, int rgb2){
        Color color1 = new Color(rgb1);
        Color color2 = new Color(rgb2);
        float[] hsb1 = new float[3];
        float[] hsb2 = new float[3];
        color1.RGBtoHSB(color1.getRed(), color1.getGreen(), color1.getBlue(), hsb1);
        color2.RGBtoHSB(color2.getRed(), color2.getGreen(), color2.getBlue(), hsb2);
        int hue1 = (int)(hsb1[0] * 360);
        int hue2 = (int)(hsb2[0] * 360);
        int hueDistance = Math.abs(hue1 - hue2);

        return hueDistance < 5 || hueDistance > 355 ; //circle concept where 0 equals to 360
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use an iterative solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have a cycle problem. This means your code may literally be running in circles (eg. 0|0 0|1 0|0 etc., or sth. alike). Also this is not size related, so I'm pretty sure that everything would be fine for a massive noise picture as how everything would be horibble for a completly red one. To avoid this issue I'd suggest not going back to pixels you already checked on, so maby try populating a list containing the pixels you already visited and then check if the one you are going to travel to is already inside there, and if it is don't go there.

Comment: I tried to add boolean matrix to flag visited pixels, but it didn't help...

Comment: So maybe my Answer was a bit incomplete, because even thoug you were potentially going back last time, size could be, unlike I stated, a problem too. To resolve this issue I'd suggest trying a loop based version of your code, so try populating a List/Stack/Queue of unchecked adjacent similar neighbours, that then gets emptied (and of course filled) in a while loop or alike. Also I think I found a slight issue with your code. You are always comparing to the color of the last pixel, not the first one. This would result in a picture of the hue spectrum to be  filled, cause neighbours are similar.

Comment: thanks, ill try the loop version. But can you explain the last sentence? I didn't get the "last and first" pixels part, can you explain the problem please?

Comment: What I tried to say is, that if your first pixel has a hue of lets say 200 then you accept every pixel in the range from 195 to 205 but if your second pixel has a hue of for example 203 the new acceptance range lies between 198 and 208 since you are checking the similarity to the second pixel, not the first. This behavior could potentially add up, so that a gradient from red to green would be all Red, because neighbouring pixels are to similar. In general, if there is high contrast you probably won't notice this, but on low contrast sections you might get unexpected results.